# Stubbing jQuery.fn method works fine in Chrome and Firefox, IE8 fails

Tags: jquery, qunit, sinon

I am writing a series of tests using sinon stubs with QUnit. The methods tested have a dependency of custom plugin we will call Foo, which I am stubbing out as such:

```
// setup
var stub = this.stub(jQuery.fn, "Foo").returns("");

// run
someProprietyMethod();

// assertions
equal(stub.args.length, 3);
equal(stub.args[0], "bar");
equal(stub.thisValues[0], "#some-selector");
// other assertions
```

I find using the sinon stubs very easy and intuitive compared to manually creating stubs. The problem is that this works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE8.

For IE8 in the test result I get:

```
Died on test #1 undefined: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Placing some debugging breadcrumbs in the tested code, it looks like $().Foo and $.fn.Foo are both seen as methods, but the test stops running after $("#some-selector").Foo() is called, when run in IE8.

Comment: what is $("#some-selector"), what element?

Comment: @Huangism it is an input, that would be used in someProprietaryMethod(). Stubbing .Foo() makes this irrelevant.

Comment: Is euaul a typo?  Not sure I understand...

Comment: @mjwenk yes just a typo. I updated code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing my own stubbing lib as it seems that existing stubbing libs can not stub a prototype of jQuery.

One of the issues seems to be losing the context of 'this' when you stub a method, if you want to test that context -- which I do.